# Visual Studio C++ Strings em Hexa

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

Estou a criar um programa em Visual Studio C++ com UI para fazer comunicação RS-232 com uns câmaras climáticas, para isso tenho que enviar um String em Hexa. A String é enviada neste formato:

```
    String^ a1 = "\x01";
    String^ a2 = "\x00";
    String^ a3 = "\x00";
    String^ a4 = "\x01";
    String^ a5 = "\x0D";
    String^ a6 = "\x0A";

    String^ final = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6;
```

O meu problema é conseguir ler a resposta das câmaras, essa resposta vem no mesmo formato da String final, ou seja, como faço para separar a String e converter para um formato Decimal?

Já tentei igual a uma variavel int, mas não tive resultados..

Comment: isso não é C++, é C#

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o **sstream**

```
std::string a1 = "\x0A";

int x;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << a1;
ss >> x;

std::string final{std::to_string(x)};
std::cout << final << "\n";
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas infelizmente nao ajudou.

No caso do \x0A é o correspondente ascii a um Line Feed. E fazendo essa conversão o que aparece é "-858993460".